# Texture Atlas doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I can't understand what is wrong. My code compiled, no errors and issues in the code, no messages in the terminal, atlas consists of .png images.
So, when I compiled my code, texture doesn't display. All that I can see is red cross. How I can solve this problem?

[image]

This is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.6, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)

        let bee = SKSpriteNode()
        bee.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
        bee.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
        self.addChild(bee)

        let beeAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "bee")
        let beeFrames : [SKTexture] =
        [beeAtlas.textureNamed("c1.png"),
        beeAtlas.textureNamed("c2.png")]

        let flyAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(beeFrames,    timePerFrame: 0.5)
        let beeAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(flyAction)
        bee.runAction(beeAction)
}

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my computer now, I've written this code, let me know if it works:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


var bee = SKSpriteNode()
var beeAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var beeFrames = [SKTexture]()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.6, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)

    beeAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "bee")

    for i in 1...beeAtlas.textureNames.count {
        var name = "c\(i).png"
        beeFrames.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
    }

    bee = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: beeAtlas.textureNames[0] as! String)
    bee.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
    bee.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)

    bee.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(beeFrames, timePerFrame: 0.5)))

    self.addChild(bee)
}
}
```

Comment: In first time when I got this issue I did all like in your video, unfortunately  it didn't help me. Can I try anything else?

Comment: could you add this line: print(bee)  after  "self.addChild(bee)" and then write here what the console says?

Comment: another reason could be that you are using an image with a resolution that is not okay with the simulator you are using. Anyhow I would try to restart the simulator (after clicking on the simulator window, top left corner select Simulator -> Reset content and settings)

Comment: 1) When I add `print(bee)` console said `<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{250, 250} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{40, 40} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00`                                                                                                   2) "Reset content and settings" doesn't help(((((((

Comment: this basically says there is no texture attached to the sprite (if it were, it should say "texture [<SKTexture> 'the name of the texture' (the size of the texure)]". What is the name of the bee in the project?

Comment: Folder name is bee.atlas pictures name: c1.png,c2.png,c3.png,c4.png

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, now console is saying `2016-05-29 16:30:09.561 Test game[2545:149104] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "c1.png" 
2016-05-29 16:30:10.052 Test game[2545:149104] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "c2.png"
2016-05-29 16:30:10.550 Test game[2545:149104] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "c3.png"
2016-05-29 16:30:11.050 Test game[2545:149104] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "c4.png"
`

Comment: how did you import the atlas folder? It could be a problem with the path

Comment: One thing you could try is to follow these steps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013290-CH1-SW1

Comment: Your last advice didn't help. I import Atlas by double clicking on main project folder then on clicking Add Files To...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, problem was solved when I tried change atlas images and folder)))))

Comment: Great! So it was probably about the resolution. No problem, I'm just glad you managed to solve it:)